# HTML Canvas gradient animate

Tags: html, canvas, gradient

In the following example , How do I do the following

1. When I create the gradients in createGradient function, Only the first arc has multiple color, the second arc has a single color
2. When the animate function is called , I would like to change only a specified gradient and not all of them

```
function init() {
    can = document.getElementById("can");
    ctx = can.getContext("2d");
    drawGradients();
    var t=setTimeout("animate()",3000);
}  

function  drawGradients() {
    var points = [[50,50,5, 50,50,50], [275,275,5, 275,275,50]];
    for ( var i=0; i < points.length; i ++ ) {
        var cords = points[i];
         createGradient ( points[i] );
    }   

}        

 function createGradient( cds) {
    var grad = ctx.createRadialGradient( cds[0],cds[1],cds[2],cds[3],cds[4],cds[5]);
    grad.addColorStop(0, 'white');
    grad.addColorStop(1, 'black');
    ctx.fillStyle=grad;
    ctx.arc(cds[3],cds[4], cds[5], 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();

}

function animate() {
    var cds =[50,50,5, 50,50,50];
        var grad = ctx.createRadialGradient( cds[0],cds[1],cds[2],cds[3],cds[4],cds[5]);
        grad.addColorStop(0, 'white');
        grad.addColorStop(1, 'blue');
        ctx.fillStyle=grad;
        ctx.arc(cds[3],cds[4], cds[5], 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fill();
    }        

</script>
```

Comment: Likely unrelated to your problem, but it is generally better to do `setTimeout(animate, 3000)` than `setTimeout("animate()", 3000)` since the latter uses `eval`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is because it is redrawing *both* arcs on the second pass. This is because you never closed the path. Since they are on the same path, they only get one gradient, so it looks like one shape didn't get a gradient, but really it is using the color from the other shape!

To fix do:

```
ctx.beginPath()
ctx.arc(cds[3],cds[4], cds[5], 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.closePath()
ctx.fill();
```

This will also fix your animate problem, and now animate will only change one of the gradients.

Working code:

http://jsfiddle.net/8AB3D/